# How to automatically insert comma or ampersand in between words in JS based on boolean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const confirmations = {
    quantity: false,
    total_price: true,
    unit_price: true
}

// Should print -> Total Price & Unit Price
// If three variables are true then should print -> Quantity, Total Price & Unit Price
```

I know this can be achieved using couple of `if...else` statements but that's really lame. Is there other way to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to work with the *variable names* dynamically, which is a huge code smell - consider another way, if at all possible. (maybe an object)

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: @mplungjan What if I have plenty of variables and I just have to do `if` until eternity?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Those are fetched using XHR Request and yup they are wrapped in an object!

Comment: Your code does not have any objects at all. If that is not the real code, please post the real code.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Updated the code!

Answer (score 4):

You could take another object for wording and then create a nice string by replacing the last two words with an ampersand and all words before join with comma.

```js
function getString(confirmations) {
    const
        nice = a => a.concat(a.splice(-2, 2).join(' & ')).join(', '),
        words = { quantity: 'Quantity', total_price: 'Total Price', unit_price: 'Unit Price' };

    return nice(Object
        .entries(confirmations)
        .filter(([, v]) => v)
        .map(([w]) => words[w])
    );
}

console.log(getString({ quantity: false, total_price: true, unit_price: true }));
console.log(getString({ quantity: true, total_price: true, unit_price: true }));
console.log(getString({ quantity: false, total_price: true, unit_price: false }));
```

Comment: @mplungjan, thank you. it's a typical writing without reading afterwards ... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```js
const confirmations1 = {quantity: false, total_price: true, unit_price: true};
const confirmations2 = {quantity: true, total_price: true, unit_price: true};

const getFormattedSentence = obj => Object
  .keys(obj)
  .filter(k => obj[k])
  .map(k => k
    .split('_')
    .map(w => w.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1))
    .join(' ')
  )
  .join(', ')
  .replace(/,(?!.*,)/gmi, ' &');
  
console.log(getFormattedSentence(confirmations1));
console.log(getFormattedSentence(confirmations2));
```

Comment: Very elegant. I had the same concept, but not the ES6 down like this

Comment: @mplungjan good your answer with use of RegExp and explanations.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt. Much slimmer after studying Yosvel Quintero's version

```js
const fmtText = obj => Object
    .keys(obj)                     // array of keys
    .filter(k => obj[k])           // take only the true ones 
    .join(", ")                    // join found keys with ,
    .replace(/_/g, " ")            // replace the underscore
    .replace(/\b([a-z])/g, x => x.toUpperCase()) // InitialCap
    .replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, ' &'); // replace last comma

const conf1 = { quantity: false, total_price: true, unit_price: true }
const conf2 = { quantity: true,  total_price: true, unit_price: true }
const conf3 = { quantity: false, total_price: true, unit_price: false }

console.log(fmtText(conf1))
console.log(fmtText(conf2))
console.log(fmtText(conf3))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job :

```
const confirmations = {
    quantity: false,
    total_price: true,
    unit_price: true
};

// filter out false values and return object keys as an array of strings
const validatedConfirmations = Object.keys(confirmations).filter((name) => confirmations[name]);

// make them human readable
const humanReadableConfirmations = validatedConfirmations.map(makeItHumanReadable);

// crunch it all to a single string
const lastConfirmationMessage = humanReadableConfirmations.pop();
const confirmationMessage = humanReadableConfirmation.join(', ') + ` & ${lastConfirmationMessage}`;
```

Careful, if only one element is true, it will display `"& Unit Price"`, you can adapt it anyway.